# Updating database at runtime

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I can't update even if my code is correct.

I tried to change the data type from `String` to `Integer` but still nothing happens.

```
Private Sub UpdateQuanLoop()
    For x As Integer = 0 To cartidentifier - 1
        UpdateQuantity(ID(x), Quantity(x))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateQuantity(S_ID As String, S_Quan As String)
    Dim finder As Integer
    access.AddParam("@proID", S_ID)
    access.ExecQuery("SELECT product_quantity FROM product WHERE product_ID = @proID;")

    Dim Z As DataRow = access.DBDT.Rows(0)
    finder = Z("product_quantity").ToString - S_Quan
    access.AddParam("@ID", S_ID)
    access.AddParam("@quan", finder)
    access.ExecQuery("UPDATE product SET product_quantity = @quan WHERE product_ID = @ID;")
    If NoErrors(True) = False OrElse access.RecordCount < 1 Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I don't have any error but the database is not updated.

Comment: This is a debugging problem, have you stepped through your code? What is `ID(x), Quantity(x)`, how is this defined `access`? There's much still missing for us to help you, please update.

Comment: Please turn option strict on in your code.  This should not compile `finder = Z("product_quantity").ToString - S_Quan`.

Comment: Im new here, how can i reply ? btw @Codexer in access it is as short number and the ID(x) and Quantity(X) are an array to identify the ID and the quantity to call it . and i use a loop to what number in array it is by using  cartidentifier

Comment: @preciousbetine how can i turn the strict mode ? how can it improve my codes ?

Comment: `Option Strict On` at the very top of your classes, better yet change it at project level...

Comment: Whatever that `access` enitity is, I suspect that adding more and more parameters to it is not correct.

Comment: from the word `access.` I'm assuming this is a Microsoft Access database using Oledb objects. If that's a correct assumption, did you know that parameters must be specified in the order in which they appear in the statement as they are only placeholders in Oledb? That being said, your update is looking for a row with an id that is matching what you're entering for quantity. Reverse those `AddParam` lines and see if that makes a difference. EDIT: Plus I guess I could just read the tags :/

Comment: As, @preciousbetine noted, you are subtracting 2 strings and setting them to an integer. Option Strict should force you to use compatible types. Among other things that will help you have stronger code practices.

Comment: Might need to see that access code. I'm curious how the same method is being used to execute a query and a nonquery sql statment.